# json_encode not working uft8 content php

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8

I have to show json data from my local database and this is Bangla font. It is working when normal print this data but when use `json_encode` then not show proper data, table field set uft8.

Here is my code which I have tried:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "newspaper");
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT news_title FROM news_content ORDER BY id DESC limit 2");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] =  $myrow['news_title'];
}
print_r($data);
echo json_encode($data);
```

this is Output when `print_r($data);`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => বুলবুলির ছানা
    [1] => টনি ডায়েসের প্রিয় সামিনা চৌধুরী, মেয়ের সেলেনা গোমেজ
)
```

and:

```
 echo json_encode($data);
```

Output is:

```
["\u09ac\u09c1\u09b2\u09ac\u09c1\u09b2\u09bf\u09b0 \u099b\u09be\u09a8\u09be","\u099f\u09a8\u09bf \u09a1\u09be\u09df\u09c7\u09b8\u09c7\u09b0 \u09aa\u09cd\u09b0\u09bf\u09df \u09b8\u09be\u09ae\u09bf\u09a8\u09be \u099a\u09cc\u09a7\u09c1\u09b0\u09c0, \u09ae\u09c7\u09df\u09c7\u09b0 \u09b8\u09c7\u09b2\u09c7\u09a8\u09be \u0997\u09cb\u09ae\u09c7\u099c"]
```

I have also tried:

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

and:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

I am not sure which problem is, so any help it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: What is the output if you try `echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`?

Comment: Well, what did you get from the try with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE?  Please do one more test:  `echo bin2hex($data[0]);`  If should get `e0a6ac e0a781 e0a6b2 e0a6ac e0a781 e0a6b2 e0a6bf e0a6b0 20e0a6 9be0a6 bee0a6 a8e0 a6be` (without any spaces).  If you don't then...

Comment: @PriidikVaikla same output when use json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: @PriidikVaikla now it is working , i think there was some other issue, write answer then i will accept it, i am not sure what was problem and why now working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is to use `json_encode` with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag.
Then Unicode characters won't be escaped.